# Synchronize logstash jdbc inputs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using multiple logstash jdbc inputs :

```
jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "../vendor/oracle/ojdbc7.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    connection_retry_attempts => 10
    connection_retry_attempts_wait_time => 5
    jdbc_validate_connection => "true"
    jdbc_connection_string => "connectionString/myDataBase"
    jdbc_user => "USER_NAME"
    jdbc_password => "PASSWORD"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement_filepath => "myPath/queryA.sql"
    tracking_column => "myTrackingcolumn"
    last_run_metadata_path => "myPath/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
    type => "documentType"
    add_field => {
          "tag" => "myFirstTag"
          }
   }

jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "../vendor/oracle/ojdbc7.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    connection_retry_attempts => 10
    connection_retry_attempts_wait_time => 5
    jdbc_validate_connection => "true"
    jdbc_connection_string => "connectionString/myDataBase"
    jdbc_user => "USER_NAME"
    jdbc_password => "PASSWORD"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement_filepath => "myPath/queryB.sql"
    tracking_column => "myTrackingcolumn"
    last_run_metadata_path => "myPath/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
    type => "documentType"
    add_field => {
          "tag" => "mySecondTag"
          }
   }

jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "../vendor/oracle/ojdbc7.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    connection_retry_attempts => 10
    connection_retry_attempts_wait_time => 5
    jdbc_validate_connection => "true"
    jdbc_connection_string => "connectionString/myDataBase"
    jdbc_user => "USER_NAME"
    jdbc_password => "PASSWORD"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement_filepath => "myPath/queryC.sql"
    tracking_column => "myTrackingcolumn"
    last_run_metadata_path => "myPath/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
    type => "documentType"
    add_field => {
          "tag" => "myThirdTag"
          }
   }
```

As there is a `SESSIONS_PER_USER limit` defined for the database I am querying this provokes the following error :

```
[31mPipeline aborted due to error {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: Java::JavaSql::SQLException: ORA-02391: 
exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit>, :backtrace=>["oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIoer.java:450)", "oracle.jdbc.driver.
T4CTTIoer.processError(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIoer.java:392)", "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIoer.java:385)",
"oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIfun.java:938)", "oracle.dbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:480)", 
"oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIfun.java:655)", "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIfun.java:249)", 
"oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:416)", "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:825)",
"oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CConnection.java:596)", "oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(oracle/jdbc/driver/PhysicalConnection.java:715)", 
"oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CConnection.java:385)", "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CDriverExtension.java:30)", 
"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver.java:564)", "RUBY.connect(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:222)", 
"RUBY.make_new(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:110)", "RUBY.make_new(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:226)", 
"RUBY.available(myPath/Env/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:199)", "RUBY._acquire(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:135)", 
"RUBY.acquire(myPath/Env/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:149)", "RUBY.sync(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:280)", 
"org.jruby.ext.thread.Mutex.synchronize(org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149)", "RUBY.sync(myPath/Env/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:280)", 
"RUBY.acquire(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:148)", "RUBY.acquire(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/extensions/connection_validator.rb:98)", 
"RUBY.hold(D:myPath/Env/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:106)", "RUBY.synchronize(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:256)", 
"RUBY.test_connection(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:266)", "RUBY.prepare_jdbc_connection(myPath/Env/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-3.1.0/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:173)", 
"RUBY.register(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-3.1.0/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:187)", "RUBY.start_inputs(myPath/Env/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:330)", "org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)", 
"RUBY.start_inputs(myPath/Env/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:329)", "RUBY.start_workers(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:180)", 
"RUBY.run(myPath/Env/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136)", 
"RUBY.start_pipeline(myPath/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:473)"], :level=>:error}?[0mstopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

How to configure these inputs so logstash perform the SQL queries sequentially and avoid exceeding the permitted sessions limit ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to perform the input sequentially.

But the option `schedule` from the jdbc input can reduce the frequency of the queries, in order to avoid the `SESSIONS_PER_USER` limit.

As it is: `schedule => "* * * * *"`, your plugin will connect to the db every minute (see [here](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*)). You can use instead `schedule => "*/15 * * * *"`, which will connect every 15 minutes (see [here](https://crontab.guru/#*/15_*_*_*_*)).

Comment: I think that this can be a workaround but not a permanent solution. I need to be sure that all the inputs are performed and avoid crashing the logstash instance. The crontab editor is great !

Comment: @Mehdi Yeah, I know it's just a workaround. A long-term solution would be to use one user per input or increase the limit (but that might not be possible in your case). Another solution (but I'm not sure it will work): set the number of workers and the batch size to 1 (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/command-line-flags.html)), so only one event is processed at a time, which _might_ block the inputs (the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.1/execution-model.html) is unclear about this)

Comment: I tried launching the logstash instance with only one pipeline worker but this doesn't solve the problem. As mentioned in the doc, it seems that the pipeline workers perform only the Filter and Output but not the Inputs ! (This option sets the number of workers that will, in parallel, execute the filter and output stages of the pipeline)

Comment: @Mehdi I thought that `blocking if all workers are busy` meant that while the pipeline processed one event, the input plugin would stop. Obviously I was wrong.

Comment: @Mehdi did you try with one worker and a batch size of one, though? My guess was to rely on the pipeline dealing with messages one at a time, blocking the input while processing.

Comment: Just tried with the pipeline batch size set to 1 and only one pipeline worker but still doesn't work. It seems that the inputs are performed simultaneously and these options (workers / batch size) affect only the filter and outputs ...

Comment: I even tried a `cron` schedule like 8 * * * * - 10 * * * * - 12 * * * * ... so they could be launched separately as you suggested but it causes the same issue.

Comment: @Mehdi I don't have any other idea.